# Save an already created object in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I am trying to create an object and then save it in a Session, then redirect to another page and use the object saved in the Session.

Here's my code, which seems to be wrong somewhere because it's not operational.

PAGE 1

```
 public FitnessClassOpportunity GetData()
    {

        return new FitnessClassOpportunity(txtId.Text, txtDescription.Text, txtLocation.Text, 
                                           Convert.ToInt32(tx2.Text), dropDownDay.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                                           txtTime.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtDuration.Text), CheckBox1.Checked, 
                                           txtDatecompleted.Text, txtNumSession.Text);

    }



 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//result from breaking point: f has the data
            FitnessClassOpportunity f = GetData();
//result from breaking point: f still has the data but Session is still NULL
        Session["object"] = f;
         Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

PAGE 2

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {

        }
        else 
        {
//add the object from the session to a list
      fitnessClassList.addFitnessClass((FitnessClassOpportunity)Session["object"]);
            UpdateListbox();
        }
      }
```

Comment: What are `fitnessClassList` and what does `addFitnessClass`? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Are you sure the redirection is considered a PostBack? My guess would be that the code is simply not executed.

Comment: I think you should move the addFitnessClass & UpdateListbox code to the _then_ branch of the if.

Comment: fitnessClassList is a list of objects . I dont get any errors its just that nothing happens when the code is executed because the Session is NULL . I cant even get that further(to go to the other page using the redirect )

Answer (score 1):

If you do a redirect it is not a postback any longer and the code to add the object to the list is not executed. Run a debugger and you will see.

EDIT:
Maybe session state is disabled. Set this in your web.config (should be default):

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="InProc"/>
  ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. My main concern was that Session just doesnt take the value that I pass to it (the F variable)

Comment: did you enable session state in your web.config?

Comment: Session["object"] would throw an exception if Session was null. If it does, you have sessionState turned off.

Comment: It doesn't. I don't even get any errors it just doesn't assign the value which is in F to the Session variable. I thought that session state is automatically enabled. I haven't enabled it, not that i know how but..still this assignment is really strange i dont get why it is not passing the information from f to the sessio

Comment: if you say that Session is null (in comment to Henk Holtermann) then it's turned off and would throw an exception. Add the sessionState element to your config and try again.